# PHPStorm 10.0.1 Ineffective code formatting

Tags: formatting, phpstorm

I've a strange problem which I cannot find solution for. I'm using PHPStorm (10.0.1 on windows 10) for developing web applications in PHP. Recently I downloaded a script. The code is formatted according to following rules

- Function declaration parenthesis have space between them and parameters
- Function call parenthesis have space between them and arguments
- Brackets have space between them similar to parenthesis
- Indentation is done using `tab`

I've configured PHPStorm with following code format settings

- No space between parenthesis in function declaration/call
- No space between brackets
- Indentation is three spaces

**Problem**
The problem is that I cannot reformat the code of *this* file automatically (using `Shift+Alt+F`). No matter what I do, PHPStorm would not format the code.

A strange thing it does is it *shows* that it has converted the `tab` to three spaces but when I open the file in, e.g., `notepad++`, I still see the `tab` indented file.

I can make edits to this file using PHPStorm just fine, it is only the auto formatting of code that is not working.

The file is encoded using `UTF8`.

**Steps I took to solve the issue without any success**

- Changed file permissions to full control
- The file originally had `CRLF` line separator which I converted to `LF` without any affect on PHPStorm's behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have opened a support ticket with [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/)?

Comment: No, I have not thought of it being a bug yet. I'm thinking I must be overlooking something?

Comment: It might not be a better big but they can quickly tell you if its intended or not